# Function to search the min value in each subarray

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I am trying to figure out the way of extracting the min. value of each subarray(4x4) of the main matrix(8x8).
Please refer to the bold part in the code to see where I am mistaking :(

```
D = [0,2,3,6,7,5,7,7,2,0,2,5,8,6,8,6,3,2,0,3,10,8,6,4,6,5,3,0,8,6,4,2,7,8,10,8,0,2,4,6,5,6,8,6,2,0,2,4,7,8,6,4,4,2,0,2,7,6,4,2,6,4,2,0]

D=np.array(D).reshape(8,8)
n=np.shape(D)[0]

def getmin_submatrix(k,n):
if k>n:
    pass

else:
    #por cada fila en el rango(8-k+1)

    for row in range(n-k+1):
        #por cada columna en el rango(8-k+1)

        for col in range(n-k+1):
            **sub=np.array(n-k+1,n-k+1)**
            #por cada fila en la submatriz (4,4)
            for p in range(row,k+row):
                #por cada columna en la submatriz (4,4)
                for q in range(col,k+col):
                    **mini=sub.min()**
            print(mini,end='')
        
        print()

getmin_submatrix(4,n)
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
and provide the necessary details including the output you are getting and your expected output

Comment: you're not even passing your matrix to your function, how is this supposed to work then?

Comment: Numpy has a function called ```numpy.amin(array)``` which will find the lowest value in an array

Comment: If I pass the main matrix (8x8) it will return the global min. of the entire matrix :( I'd like to return every minimum of every possible combination of 4x4 submatrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will iterate through the matrix, you can define a submatrix-size and the stride and prints you the min for each submatrix.

```
import numpy as np

D = [0,2,3,6,7,5,7,7,2,0,2,5,8,6,8,6,3,2,0,3,10,8,6,4,6,5,3,0,8,6,4,2,7,8,10,8,0,2,4,6,5,6,8,6,2,0,2,4,7,8,6,4,4,2,0,2,7,6,4,2,6,4,2,0]

D=np.array(D).reshape(8,8)
n=np.shape(D)[0]

def find_min(M, k, stride):
    for row in range(0, M.shape[0]-k+1, stride):
        for column in range(0, M.shape[1]-k+1, stride):
            print(M[row:row+k, column:column+k].min())

find_min(D, 4, 1)
```